# What's the best method for having an XSLT presentation layer in Android?

Tags: android, xslt

I'm fairly new to Android, but have done lots of Java/JSP development and HTML over the last 10 years. So I'm not real familiar with what Android can do. With this current project I'm working on, I'm going to have to read XML/XSLT files and display them in an Adroid application. However, there are a couple caveats:
1. The links in the page should be handled within my own app and not the default web browser (except external links)
2. The XSLT will be stored locally, with the XML retrieved online.

I don't want to waste hours trying to fit a square peg in a round hole if anyone has already done something like this and knows what to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [webview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). 
From the documentation:

> A View that displays web pages. This class is the basis upon which
>   you can roll your own web browser or simply display some online
>   content within your Activity. It uses the WebKit rendering engine to
>   display web pages and includes methods to navigate forward and
>   backward through a history, zoom in and out, perform text searches and
>   more.

It will render your html like the browser, but you have plenty of ways to control its behavior and the presentation of it in your app.

It is very easy to get started with, a good start is the google [Hello, WebView tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html)

Comment: Thanks. That seems simple enough for displaying the page. Where would i put the XSLT file locally on the device? And how should it be referenced in the XML so that the WebView looks for the file locally as opposed to on the webserver?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866871/how-to-reference-link-to-a-css-file-styling-elements-in-a-webview-for-android) answer seems to suggest that you can reference them as a url like this: file:///android_res/raw/filename.xsl. This file is placed in the res folder of your android project

Comment: Sorry, the file should be placed in your res/raw folder when it is referenced file:///android_res/raw/filename.xsl